# Is minimizing this sql query for category/product relationship necessary?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure as follows and I want to select 
all active categories 
with active products 
of a particular parent ID.

So if I plug in a particular parentID, I only get relevant active subcategories of the parent that contains active products.

This is my sql (mysql) so far which works, but looks pretty nasty, and for the sake of academia I want to know if there's a better way. It would seem to me that selecting all of the productIDs that are active to filter the results is kind of a waste, but I can't figure a way around this, or does mysql figure out the best way to process this query?

```
(many-to-many upon itself)
categories
----------
categoryID
parentID
name
isActive (bool)

(linker table between categories and product)
productCategories
-----------------
productID
categoryID

products
--------
productID
name
isActive (bool)


SELECT productCategories.categoryID, categories.* FROM productCategories
                LEFT JOIN categories ON
                    productCategories.categoryID = categories.categoryID
                WHERE 
                    productCategories.categoryID IN 
                    (SELECT categoryID FROM categories WHERE parentID = {$parentID} AND isActive = 1)
                    AND
                    productCategories.productID IN
                    (SELECT productID FROM products WHERE isActive = 1)
                GROUP BY productCategories.categoryID
```

Comment: A good question is "what is your definition of `better`?"  Faster (in seconds), fewer resources (such as cpu cycles), more readable, more maintainable/adaptable, fewer lines of code, etc?

Comment: Fewer lines of code then fewer cpu cycles. Wouldn't cpu cycles mean faster?

Comment: Not if you get parallelism.  You could use 2 cores (instead of 1), and save 25% of the time.  Overall you're using 150% of the cpu time, but taking 75% of the actual time.

Comment: Note: In SQL, fewer lines of code often is Not the most efficient solution.  That's not to say it's not a valid objective, but assuming one means the other is a trap I often have to rescue people from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative layout could be as follows...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    productCategories.categoryID
  FROM
    productCategories
  INNER JOIN
    categories
      ON categories.categoryID = productCategories.parentID
  INNER JOIN
    products
      ON products.productID    = productCategories.productID
  WHERE 
    categories.parentID = {$parentID}
    AND categories.isActive = 1
    AND products.isActive = 1
  GROUP BY
    productCategories.categoryID
)
  AS category_map
LEFT JOIN
  categories AS [children]
    ON category_map.categoryID = categories.categoryID
```

Comment: close enough to perfect for me. Exactly what I was looking for and I learned a little bit about how to use INNER JOIN